# Position I applied for is different once I started. What do I put on my resume?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, title

I applied for a position that was posted on the company website, interviewed and got the job offer. Once I started, I noticed under the companies directory that there's a different role under my name. What do I do about this? I don't want my next employer thinking I am lying about my position.

Comment: Please [edit] in the specific titles; the answers may depend on that (also if that question David points to is a duplicate or not).

Comment: The only entity who can tell you what your job title is is your employer. Ask them.

Comment: @DavidK I don't think it's a duplicate - it seems like there might be a mismatch between the job title OP thought they were hired for and the job title they actually have.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, but the OP's primary concern appears to be about how to explain this to their *next* employer, not about bringing this up with their current employer.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, but if you don't know what your job title is, the first step is probably to figure that out. It seems like a reasonable question to ask one's employer. The answers on the post you linked mostly assumes OP already knows their official job title - if you get rid of that assumption, the answers mostly fall apart.

Comment: I looked at the duplicate answer suggested and I was talking about the title of the position Let's say for example I was hired as a "Application Engineer" but the job title once hired says "Technical Engineer" two totally different areas but seems like the work is the same in the company

Comment: For what it's worth, I did not vote to close as duplicate, but rather as: Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors.

Comment: @Dukeling Yeah, I've always found it annoying that if you vote to close but not for the majority reason, it still puts you in with everyone else.

Comment: Your hiring paperwork should tell you what your title is. Look it up there. If what is showing is different, go to HR and point this out as a mistake to fix. If it is not a mistake but you are doing the duties of job you thought you were getting, your resume should have your existing title but describe the duties. If they are too far off (such as QA Engineer vice Software Developer) put the real title in () after the official title and explain why in the cover letter. If the duties match the new title, then don't try to pretend it is the other thing.

Comment: I feel like the same logic still applies, you list what you were hire as then the duties you performed. You could always ask you boss what you were hired as, but my guess would be when they look through the paper work to see your title it will be the same as the posting. Can you tell the actualy situation IE: The job you applied for is X title and what title you think is more descriptive of your job duties?

Comment: @HLGEM that is actually enough to be answer!

Comment: Well, I still have the old emails I got once I applied and it state "X" position but once I got an offer, the letter stated "Y" position. I just don't know why they would lie on the job posting. So in this case, the offical job the one posted on the companies website or the one that I got once hired? I honestly don't want a future employer thinking I'm inflating my job title....

Comment: I believe this is not a duplicate and a genuine question. A lot of companies have their internal mapping of industry standard titles. Nobody knows what a T2 Developer means on a specific company. Question is, should a person mention the job title they applied or the internal position name to their CVs?